# Factory using $resource return undefined object

Tags: angularjs, resources, factory

I have a factory using $resource but cant use object generated as undefined
I've seen so many reponses regarding that problem that i am more and more confusing

here is my factory

```
angular.module('contrats')
    .factory('Contrats', ['$resource',
        function($resource) {
            return $resource('contrats/:contratId', { contratId: '@_id'}, {
                update: {method: 'PUT'},
            });
        }
]);
```

here is my controler

```
// Contrats controller
var app = angular.module('contrats')
.controller ('ContratsController', 
['$scope' , '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Contrats', function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Contrats)
    {
            $scope.contrats = Contrats.query();
            $scope.nbctrt = $scope.contrats.length;
})];
```

$scope.contrats.length  = > generate error can't get property of undefined

I'stuck for days with that and dont understand Thanks for your advices to a newbie

Comment: Can you `$scope.contrats = Contrats.query(function(success) { console.log(success);}, function(error){ console.log(error);} )` to see what you get in response to your query?

Comment: Hi @klskl  i added  '$scope.contrats = Contrats.query(function(success) { console.log(success);}, function(error){ console.log(error);} )
console.log('nb contrats',$scope.contrats.length);
console.log('contrat[0]:' , $scope.contrat[0]);'      this gives  'nb contrats 0 contrat[0]: undefined  [Resource, Resource,.... Resource, $promise: Object, $resolved: true]  ... succes log arrives after .length & [] log' .... thx for ideas

Comment: from what I understand `console.log('contrat[0]:' , $scope.contrat[0]);` is undefined because it should be `contrats[0]` not `contrat[0]` ? Also, try doing that log inside the success function, so the query is complete before logging

Comment: that's it ... when i evaluate any value inside success function it works because then the query is complete . thx a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify my comment.

Add you logs inside the success function, so that the query is complete before logging, something like this

```
$scope.contrats = Contrats.query(function(success) { 
   // response from query
   console.log(success); 

   // length of $scope.contrats
   console.log('nb contrats',$scope.contrats.length); 
   // first item in $scope.contrats
   console.log('contrats[0]:' , $scope.contrats[0]);

}, function(error){
   console.log(error); 
});
```